# Added new section to FAQ detailing what to include in a question

Tags: discussion

I added a new section called "WHAT TO INCLUDE IN YOUR QUESTION" in the "What kind of questions can I ask here?" FAQ.

Feel free to edit as you see fit:
https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/faq#questions

Comment: Love this addition, excellent.

Comment: Nice. Looks good!

Comment: Looks great - some of that can probably be repurposed and used across a lot of the code-centric Stackexchange sites. One nitpick: it should be "Err on the side of more information for a prompt answer." Err, not Error. (I don't see how to make edits to the page, or I'd do so.)

Comment: You might need a certain rep to edit. Edit completed....